# slimscroll not behaving like usual with 100% height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slimscroll

Slimscroll appears to not be behaving as usual, I have the height set to 100% and it scrolls fine and the content is 100% although when I keep dragging the scrollbar down it goes past 100% e.g it drags further then the display of the content, by about 250 - 300 px.

I have used this code.

```
$("#r_a").load("sidebar.php", function() {
$("#r_a").slimScroll({
height: '100%',
alwaysVisible: true,
position: 'right'
});
});
```

for some reason this code plays a pivital role in initializing the slimscroll correctly also -
$('#righter').css({'height':(($(window).height())+180)+'px'});

```
#righter is the container of #r_a
```

when the screen is zoomed all the way out slimscroll functions perfectly.

here is the website, http://www.2click4.com/new/home3.php